# Access modifiers on interface members in C#

Tags: c#, interface, access-modifiers, explicit-interface

I am getting a compile error from the following property. 
The error is:

> "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item"

```
public System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary IWorkItemControl.Properties
{
    get { return properties; }
    set { properties = value; }
}
```

but if I remove the `IWorkItemControl` it compiles fine.

Why am I getting this error and what is the difference of having / not having the interface name in the signature?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) does not let you specify any access modifiers. When you implement an interface member explicitly (by specifying the interface name before the member name), you can access that member **only using that interface**. Basically, if you do:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary IWorkItemControl.Properties
{
    get { return properties; }
    set { properties = value; }
}
```

You can't do:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
var test = x.Properties; // fails to compile
// You should do:
var test = ((IWorkItemControl)x).Properties; // accessible through the interface
```

There are several use cases for EII. For example, you want to provide a `Close` method for your class to free up acquired resources but you still want to implement `IDisposable`. You could do:

```
class Test : IDisposable {
    public void Close() {
        // Frees up resources
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        Close();
    }
}
```

This way, the consumers of class can only call `Close` directly (and they won't even see `Dispose` in Intellisense list) but you can still use the `Test` class wherever an `IDisposable` is expected (e.g. in a `using` statement).

Another use case for EII is providing different implementations of an identically named interface member for two interfaces:

```
interface IOne {
   bool Property { get; }
}

interface ITwo {
   string Property { get; }
}

class Test : IOne, ITwo {
   bool IOne.Property { ... }
   string ITwo.Property { ... }
}
```

As you see, without EII it's **not even possible** to implement both interfaces of this example in a single class (as the properties differ just in return type). In other cases, you might want to intentionally provide different behavior for individual views of a class through different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

All elements of an interface must be public.
After all, an interface *is* the public view of an object.

Since **Properties** is an element of an interface **IWorkItemControl**, it is already public, and you cannot specify its access level, even to redundantly specify that it is public.

Comment: This is not a very strong reason as you still have to manually specify public for all implicitly implemented members. If that was the case, the compiler could automatically assume those as public too.