# How to filter a collection inside a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-collections

I have a two class which is having following properties

```
 Class A
  {
      public int CustID { get; set; }
      public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
  }
  Class B
  {
      public int EmpId{ get; set; }
      public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
  }
```

I created one generic method which accepts all these classes.'isProcessed' property is common in both these classes.

```
public void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1)
{

}
```

I need following things

1. Inside ProcessData method i want to filter items which is having
   isProcessed flag is "True".
2. Also i want to iterate this collection and need to set values for IsProcessed property.

Note:  I am preferring solution using reflection,since property name is constant (ie "IsProcessed")

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Can you make `A` and `B` implement the same interface?

Comment: Any reason your classes `A` and `B` either don't have a common ancestor or expose an interface? That would solve the problem easily.

Comment: since isProcessed will be common to Class A & B,i don't plan to change class structure

Comment: I think you should have common interface with isProcessed() method, and both classes should implement it. So you can use your interface instead if <T>.

Comment: `...since property name is constant` <= what does that mean? Do you mean it will never change? In that case using an interface is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to ensure that both classes implement a common interface and constrain your generic method. For example:

```
public interface IProcessable
{
    bool isProcessed { get; set; }
}
public class A : IProcessable
{
    public int CustID { get; set; }
    public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
}

public class B : IProcessable
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
}
```

Now your method would look like this:

```
public void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1)
    where T : IProcessable // <-- generic constraint added
{
    foreach (var element in param1)
    {
        element.isProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

Another option which is more useful if you cannot use an interface or the property names vary, is to pass in an `Action<T>` as a parameter to your method. For example:

```
public void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1, Action<T> func)
{
    foreach (var element in param1)
    {
        func(element);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
ProceesData<A>(list, "", x => x.isProcessed = true);
```

Comment: You don't even need a generic method, simply have it take a `IList<IProcessable>`.

Comment: @DavidG. i am preferring solution using reflection,since property name is constant "IsProcessed"

Comment: @vmb Reflection is very clunky and slow, I would not advise that

Comment: @David . i don't have a freedom to change existing class structure

Comment: @vmb OK, I've given you another option

Comment: @GabrielNegut - That would not work if you had an instance of type `List<A>` and wanted to pass it to the method.

Comment: @GabrielNegut: No, `IList<T>` is not covariant (it is `IList<T>` not `IList<out T>`). This means that you could call the generic method with an IList<A>, IList<B> or IList<IProcessable> but only the latter is "convertible" to IList<IProcessable>. If you can use `IEnumerable<out T>` instead of `IList`, a non-generic method works fine though.

Comment: I need a solution similar to typeof(T).GetProperty("IsProcessed")

Comment: @vmb But *why*? The second option will do the job for you.

Comment: @DavidG .. i want to set value for IsProcessd inside ProcessData,and planning to recursively call this function

Comment: @vmb So why does this method not work for you? If you are calling this a lot, then reflection could be a terribly slow solution.

Comment: @DavidG .i am bit confused..When we doing like this,  foreach (var element in param1)
            {
                func(element);
            } ....Where we will get filtered list (ie ISProcessed == true)

Comment: @DavidG ..Also second question is unanswered..How can set value for IsProceed property inside this generic method

Comment: @vmb Both methods I show you will set the `isProcessed` property. Are you saying you only want to filter out the elements where that property is true?

Comment: @vmb So why do you need a generic method at all? Just do `var filteredList = list.Where(e => e.isProcessed);`

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface, like `IProcessData`, that contains a Boolean property, `IsProcessed`.  Have both classes implement this interface.  Change your `ProcessData` method so that it no longer has the generic notation (`<T>`) and accepts an `IList<IProcessData>`.  Then perform your filtering and iterations on the param1 data.

Comment: i am preferring solution using reflection,since property name is constant "IsProcessed"

Comment: I need a solution similar to typeof(T).GetProperty("IsProcessed")

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I am preferring solution using reflection

This method will iterate the collection, filter according to `propertyName` and `filterValue` and set the values to the `newValue` using reflection:

```
public void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1, string propertyName, 
                                  object filterValue, object newValue)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    object value;

    for (int i = param1.Count; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        value = pi.GetValue(param1[i]);
        if (value.Equals(filterValue))
        {
            pi.SetValue(param1[i], newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
ProceesData<A>(a_list, "", "isProcessed", false, true);
```

**Disclaimer:**

Although this is possible. It is far from being save. If you hand over the wrong property name it will fail! I would recommend to use the second approach by @DavidG handing over an `Action` delegate. This will make the entire processing more sound and less prone to error. I would suggest to use here a normal reverse for-loop, because this would even allow you to delete items from you collection.

```
public static void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1, Action<T> func)
{            
    for (int i = param1.Count; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        func(param1[i]);
    }
}
```

This call will give you the same result:

```
ProceesData<A>(a_list, "", (x)=> { if (!x.isProcessed) x.isProcessed = true; });
```

You get even more flexible by this approach because you can decide at each call what this method is supposed to do. You can even remove the processed items from the collection:

```
ProceesData<A>(a_list, "", (x)=> { if (!x.isProcessed) a_list.Remove(x); });
```

One difference remains though. Because if you would have a collection which would contain both elements `A` and `B` like this: (I used an exemplary constructor for this case)

```
List<object> obj_list = new List<object>()
{
    new A(1, false),
    new B(2, true),
    new A(3, false),
    new B(4, false),
};
```

You would have to use the `dynamic` data type for the `Action` overload:

```
ProceesData<dynamic>(obj_list, "", (x) => { if (!x.isProcessed) obj_list.Remove(x); });
```

And for the reflection way of doing things you would need to check at each iteration the type. This would increase processing time.

```
public static void ProceesData<T>(IList<T> param1, string date1, string propertyName, object filterValue, object newValue)
{
    for (int i = param1.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = param1[i].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        object value;

        value = pi.GetValue(param1[i]);
        if (value.Equals(filterValue))
        {
            pi.SetValue(param1[i], newValue);
        }
    }
}
```