# Property is accessible when using interface constraint in collections?

Tags: c#, collections, interface, constraints

What i really want is to understand is why when using an interface as  a constraint on a generic class I am able to access the "Nume" property that I defined in a class that implements that interface. My questions are:

- 1. Why do I have to add the interface as a constraint in the generic class while I already implemented it in the initial Tr class?
- 2. Why I cannot access the property directly from the class and why I am able to access it by implementing the interface?

Without the interface I cannot access the property from the Tr class, so I implemented the solution found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231646/how-to-access-properties-of-a-class-from-a-generic-method-c-sharp/42231682) Stackoverflow question,it seems to work but i cannot understand exactly why.

I also looked on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)  Microsoft documentation.

```
interface GET
{
    int Nume { get; }
}

class Tr : GET 
{
    public int Nume { get; }

    public Tr() { }

    public Tr(int num)
    {
        this.Nume = num;
    }
}

class Program<Tr> where Tr : GET
{
   static List<Tr> lst = new List<Tr>();

    public void Test(Tr merge)
    {           
        lst.Add(merge);
        foreach (Tr cadt in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Numarul este {cadt.Nume}");
        }
    }     
}

class MainC
{      
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tr cc = new Tr(2);

        Program<Tr> cls = new Program<Tr>();
        cls.Test(cc);
    }        
}
```

I expected This code to work without the help of an interface, but it crashed. It works with the help of the interface.

Comment: "but it crashed" isn't helpful, what was the exact error? Include the message in your question. The code you posted runs without error, we need more information.

Comment: @Workout Channel, as I got that from the question, the error was there without `where Tr : GET` constraint and you had to add it to fix the error. Right?

Comment: @Alex Yes.I used the solution provided in the stackoverflow link,but the reason why I posted this question is hopefully someone to explain me why,by implementing the interface,the code worked.

Comment: @Workout Channel, see the update to my answer. It gives all the explanation.

Comment: Thank You @Alex.So,from my understanding:The <Tr> is just a type parameter,it has nothing to do with the actually Tr class and it can be replace by anything.The compiler knows of the Nume property because the <Tr> type parameter implements the interface on which the Nume property is defined,so to compiler now knows that the object that will replace the <Tr> has to contain the Nume property.Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: Also 2 more questions:
You always need to implement the interface as a  constraint to the generic in order to access the properties from a class?
The property Nume is accessed directly from the interface or,I guess,is accessed at runtime from the Tr class and the interface is just a reference?

Comment: @Workout Channel, you got it right. For your first question it is yes. For the second one read more about implicit and explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `class Program<Tr> where Tr : GET` `Tr` is a **type parameter**, it's **just a name** and it has **nothing** to do with `Tr` **class**. So it **does not** implement `GET` and it **does not have** to provide `Nume` property. But if you put the constraint `where Tr : GET` the situation changes. Now it **does** implement `GET` and it **does have** to provide `Nume` property.

Your class is equivalent to:

```
class Program<T> where T : GET
{
    static List<T> lst = new List<T>();

    public void Test(T merge)
    {
        lst.Add(merge);
        foreach (T cadt in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Numarul este {cadt.Nume}");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the reason why

- you have to add the interface as a constraint in the generic class
- you cannot access the property directly from the class
- you are able to access it by implementing the interface

Using `<Tr>` makes confusion. If I were a compiler developer I'd treat it as an error (a warning at least) and I wouldn't let such a code to compile.

Here is an illustration of `<Tr>` in `class Program<Tr>` is not `Tr` class.
[image]

Comment: How can you possibly answer the question when it isn't even complete? The code posted runs without error.

Comment: @DavidG, as I got that from the question, the error was there without `where Tr : GET` constraint and OP had to add it to fix the error.