# How to use my method with differents parameters with generics type?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, generic-type-parameters

I have two methods with same code inside and with different param types. How to use one generic method without duplicate method in C# and ASP.NET Core?

My method1:

```
public async Task<OrderDto> ExecuteOrderOperations(CreateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Domain.Entities.FoodBusiness foodBusiness)
{
    // code....
}
```

My method 2 :

```
public async Task<OrderDto> ExecuteOrderOperationsForSH(CreateOrderCommandSH request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Domain.Entities.FoodBusiness foodBusiness)
{
    // same code....
}
```

Comment: How can it be the "same code" if the parameter type changed? How is the first parameter used in each of the methods? Did you happen to call a common method in both of those types?

Comment: CreateOrderCommand : IRequest<OrderDto>

Comment: CreateOrderSHCommand : IRequest<HotelOrder>

Comment: If OrderDto and HotelDto contain the same properties that are accessed within this method, you could apply an interface to them and change the parameter type to that interface.

Answer (score -2):

If `CreateOrderCommand` and `CreateOrderCommandSH` looks similar, **I suggest  extracting their common functionalities to a base class or interface**.
Then you can call the method with both types by changing the parameter to be the inherited type:

```
public async Task<OrderDto> ExecuteOrderOperations(CreateOrderBase request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Domain.Entities.FoodBusiness foodBusiness)
{
    //code...
}
```

If this is not possible, you can't do much else than an ugly workaround which **I would not recommend**.
You could only apply 1 class type constraint for a generic parameter, so ensuring `T` is really one of those 2 classes is not possible at compile time.
Your only remaining solution is to type check in the method body:

```
public async Task<OrderDto> ExecuteOrderOperations<T>(T request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Domain.Entities.FoodBusiness foodBusiness)
{
    switch(request)
    {
        case CreateOrderCommand command:
            //code...
            break;
        case CreateOrderCommandSH commandSH:
            //code...
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public async Task<OrderDto> ExecuteOrderOperations<T>(T request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Domain.Entities.FoodBusiness foodBusiness)
{
    // code....
}
```

Comment: What will this do? You can't access any properties of T within `// code`.

Comment: Pravin007 i can't access any property of T

Comment: you are asking for generic method, which means you are not accessing any property of first param :-)

Comment: no , i need to access to propeties of first params , what should i do now ?!

Comment: You can access property by using reflection. check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231646/how-to-access-properties-of-a-class-from-a-generic-method-c-sharp