# What accessibility does an explicitly implemented method have?

Tags: c#, interface

So my friend said that explicitly implemented interface methods are private.

Consider this example for the argument:

```
interface ITest
{
    void Test();
}

class Test : ITest
{
    // IS THIS METHOD PRIVATE?
    void ITest.Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What am I?");
    }
}
```

I did not believe that and I will list the arguments on both sides:

Him:

- [You cannot specify any access modifiers on an explicitly implemented method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077827/10883465) and [if no access modifier is specified, it will use the lowest possible which should be private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c/2521492#2521492) hence the method is private.
- In [this interview at around 30:30](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/A-Preview-of-C-8-with-Mads-Torgersen#time=30m30s) it sounds as they say that explicitly implemented method can be private which I do believe (I mean it's Mads Torgensen) but I don't why that would be the case.

Me:

- You cannot access the `Test` method from inside the class unless you cast yourself to `ITest` (which is how explicitly implemented methods work but shouldn't you be able to call the method from inside the class if it really was a private method inside that class?)
- When you cast a `Test`-instance to `ITest`, the `Test` method becomes publicly available and can be called from anywhere hence it cannot be private.
- I don't know how credible this is but in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521467/10883465) it is stated that "explicitly implemented interface member" are public.

I think we both know how Explicit Interface Implementation works and how to use it but right here we aren't sure who's right.
The question really boils down to this:

**Can you call the `Test` method in the `Test` class a "private method"?**

Comment: it has `private` access level

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Is there a way to back that up by some specs or maybe through the IL?

Comment: The [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces) puts it diplomatically: "Explicit interface member implementations have different accessibility characteristics than other members. Because explicit interface member implementations are never accessible through their fully qualified name in a method invocation or a property access, they are in a sense private. However, since they can be accessed through an interface instance, they are in a sense also public." As far as IL is concerned, though, they're private.

Comment: Okay so I guess I was not right then :) @JeroenMostert I think that comment might be worth to put as answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit interface methods have `private` access level.

Let's have a look (with a help of *Reflection*):

```
  using System.Reflection;

 ...

  var result = typeof(Test)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(info => $"{(info.IsPrivate ? "private" : "not private")} {info.Name}");

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);

  Consolw.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
private WFA_Junk_4.Form1.ITest.Test // <- Method of interest
not private Equals
not private GetHashCode
not private Finalize
not private GetType
not private MemberwiseClone
not private ToString
```

So we can't execute them explictly:

```
Test test = new Test();

// ITest.Test() call which is OK
(test as ITest).Test();

// Doesn't compile: 
//   1. Private method
//   2. Wrong name; should be typeof(ITest).FullName.Test() which is not allowed 
test.Test();
```

Since we can't put methods name as it is, the only way, as I can see to call `ITest.Test` directly is reflection:

```
class Test : ITest {
  ...
  public void SomeMethod() 
  {
     // we can't put method's name as it is `SomeNamespace.ITest.Test`
     // Let's find it and execute
     var method = this
       .GetType()
       .GetMethod($"{(typeof(ITest)).FullName}.Test", 
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

     method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I was looking for. Do you by any chance know why `test.Test()` in this case is equally not permitted as `this.Test()` inside the `Test` class? Surely if it was _just private_ you should be able to do that right?

Comment: Also if you try to call `test.Test()` you get `'Demo.Test' does not contain a definition for 'Test' and no extension method 'Test' accepting a first argument of type 'Demo.Test' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` as a compiler error. However if you try to call a method which is explicitly specified as private you get `'Demo.Test.PrivateMethod()' is inaccessible due to its protection level`. Why does the first case not throw the same as the second one? Would both errors be accurate for the first case?

Comment: @Joelius: not only we have `private` access, but the method's name which prevent us to call it directly; the only way as I can see to call it explicitly (without cast to interface) is reflection

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The fact that the method cannot be called from within the class is how you know it's *not* private.  If it were private, *you would be able to call it*.  You can't argue that the numerous ways in which it doesn't behave at all like a private method are what make it private.

Comment: With regard to your last code example using reflection, why not just call Test() like you would normally do by casting the reference (`this` in this case) to the interface type? Basically like you did in your 2nd code snippet: `public void SomeMethod() { ((ITest) this).Test(); }` (maybe i misunderstood what you were trying to show there in your last code example, though...)